# Google document api iframe bandwidth limit

Tags: php, pdf, iframe, google-docs, pdf-reader

in my site i have an iframe like this that open a pdf

```
< iframe style="width: 100%; height: 895px; border: 0px; position: relative; top: 56px;" src="https://docs.google.com/gview?url=http://www.example.com/3155309.pdf&embedded=true"></iframe>
```

I'm using google docs as a genuine online pdf reader on my website.
This is a facsimile url https://docs.google.com/gview?url=http://www.example.com/3155309.pdf&embedded=true

What I want to know is what is the bandwidth limit of google docs?

As if I refresh the page several times this message appears:

**You have reached your bandwidth limit for viewing or downloading files that are not in Google Docs format. Please check back later. 
To try to download the original document, click here.**

The real problem is that I do not know if there is a limit on monthly, weekly, daily or hourly! When I see that error, if I reload the page a good 80% percent of the time it 
disappears.

I would like to know if it is possible to no-display this message again (even paying directly google in some way)?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

From https://support.google.com/a/answer/1071518?hl=en

**`To help keep our systems healthy and your account safe, all Google Apps accounts have a limited amount of bandwidth. Certain activities that transfer large amounts of data in a short period of time, like synchronizing a Gmail account to a mobile phone or mail client, can cause an account to reach the bandwidth limit.`**

Comment: ok... but i don't use 300 MB in an hour.. my biggest pdf is 100 KB... i don't understand why sometimes appears this error and if i reload the page it disappears

Comment: @user2437305 I think, It's a problem with Google Docs falsely triggering a bandwidth error. There are bandwidth limitations with Google accounts but under normal circumstances these wouldn't be reached.